# Get rotation Euler from normal

Tags: normals, geometry

Documentation for [Distribute Point on Faces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/distribute_points_on_faces.html) node for geometry nodes says "Rotation:
An XYZ Euler rotation built from the normal attribute for convenience. Such a value can also be built from the normal with the Rotate Euler Node."

What settings does one need to use to get the Euler rotation from the normal?

Answer (score 0):

Did you learn how to do this?

I found a way to do this with a helper object and custom orientations (As in here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8_66wGqCbM) but it's too tedious to do for 126 objects. I would only need to calculate the difference with the face's normal rotation with the global 0,0,0.

I myself have a problem with a sphere that is created with an "Goldberg Polyhedra" algorythm that creates hexagon faces on the surface that can be used as nodes for our game objects and creates a sphere like level where the objects will be placed on the sphere.

[image: Problem: Rotation of a hexagon is 0,0,0]

The problem is that to align the objects in Unity at the surface of the hexagon or even replace the hexagon in the model with a hexagon of our own, we need to know the local rotation that is needed to use to a object that is aligned 0,0,0 on a global axis.

Because this hexagon has 0,0,0 local value we cannot use that as a reference to turn the object in the Unity. As it is we would need to rotate hexagon object in Blender to 0,0,0 in the global axis and then return it to the original rotation (Sphere shaped) with the euler angles calculated from global 0,0,0.

With this difference we could align the hexagons created in Unity to same rotations as hexagons are in Blender.. But I cannot seem to find a way to do this. At least for all of the parts together.

Comment: Welcome to Blender stack exchange! What I ended up doing is using align to vector, like here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3gbV.jpg. However, I don't think this will help you with your question. I encourage you to ask your question as a new one; here now one will see it!